# Web App Libraries empty in Eclipse - no "jars" found

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jar

Recently my Spring MVC Java app, developed in Eclipse Indigo, seemed to lose it's connection to my "lib" folder where all my jars are (there were no jars found for my project anymore).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For me, the fix was simple:

- Go here in the Eclipse menu: Project | Properties | Project Facets
- Ensure "Java" and "Dynamic Web Project" are selected
- Click OK

You *may* need to also do this:

- Go here in the Eclipse menu: Project | Properties | Java Build Path | Libraries
- Remove "Web App Libraries"
- Click "Add Library"
- Choose "Web App Library". Click "Next"
- Choose your project in the drop down
- Click OK

Comment: Hm.  With eclipse mars, this still seems to be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

For me, Brad Parks's answer didn't worked in Eclipse Luna ( 4.4.2 )  i.e. Adding **Web App Libraries** had no effect ..that remained empty.

What I had to is to configure **Web Deployment Assembly** ...My lib was in WEB-INF which was again like - `/{project}/web/WEB-INF/lib`  and when I added a **Deployment Assembly** entry like shown below ,

[image]

Then below these two I had an entry for every jar from `{project}/web/WEB-INF/lib` directory with Deploy Path as `WEB-INF/lib`.

This Deployment Assembly automatically populated my `Web App Libraries`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have imported your existing project then , first add Server(Window>Preference>Server>Run Time environment) to your work space and then re-import your project.

or Option 2 
Goto Project properties > Targeted RunTimes and select your server

This should add web library to your project.